# sed is adding character to start of word vs end

Tags: bash, unix, sed, passwords, word-list

So I'm trying to add a "!" to the end of every word in my placesCapEx file from my placesCap file

This is what it looks like: 
`Yugoslavian
Zambia
Zambian
Zomba`

This is what I want it to look like: 
`Yugoslavian!
Zambia!
Zambian!
Zomba!`

I've tried `sed 's/$/\!/' Wordlists/placesCap > Wordlists/placesCapEx` and just `sed 's/$/!/' Wordlists/placesCap > Wordlists/placesCapEx`

What happens is when I run this and then `cat Wordlists/placesCapEx` it outputs
`!ugoslavian
!ambia
!ambian
!omba`

I've done some research and someone stated something about it being a Unix thing but they never went into detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simpler sed command should work fine for a text file where end-of-line is a single newline character. You likely have "dos" format files here (carriage return / linefeed).

Consider:

```
$ cat zippy
Zippy
$ od -c zippy
0000000   Z   i   p   p   y  \r  \n
0000007
$ sed 's/$/!/' zippy
!ippy
$ sed 's/$/!/' zippy | od -c
0000000   Z   i   p   p   y  \r   !  \n
0000010
```

You're seeing the effect of \r displayed on a terminal: move the cursor to start of line, print the '!', newline goes to next line.

To handle the presence of \r\n pairs as your end-of-line character, you might try:

```
$ sed 's/\r*$/!/' zippy
Zippy!
```

...assuming your sed honors the \r as mine (GNU sed 4.2.2) does.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you! And thanks for the explanation of the problem as well!